# Use liquid in css file within Jekyll environment

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am looking for an answer of how to use Liquid for my background image path in css file and hoping the image can be seen in localhost and on Github at the same time.

The first background path only worked on Github and the second one only worked in localhost. Is there any way to achieve what I want without comment out the code every time I commit to Github? I was thinking maybe I need to use {{%%}} so I read the documentation from Jekyll and looked up for answers but still no luck.

**CSS**

```
---
---

.content-wrapper {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 2600px;
  background: url({{site.baseurl}}/_site/assets/img/dummy_blog_content.jpg);
  background: url({{site.url}}{{site.baseurl}}/assets/img/dummy_blog_content.jpg);
}
```

**YML**

```
baseurl: /project
exclude: ["README.md"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `absolute_url` to automatically prepend the `url` and `base_url` in liquid **but** that should be done in your templates:

```
{{ "/assets/style.css" | absolute_url }}
```

The generated url shouldn't have `_site` in it, as that won't work in Github pages. **In your template** refer to your css location, in this case `/assets/style.css`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ '/assets/style.css' | absolute_url }}">
```

Comment: Wondering how come **absolute_url** is not in the [document](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/) or I missed it.